# Can I get by without a coolant drain bolt washer in my 1997 accord

Tags: honda, coolant, cooling-system, accord

I just did a huge timing belt and seals job that included replacing the coolant in my 1997 accord with the f22b2 engine.  The drain bot washer fell out, and I didn't notice it, so I put back the drain bolt without its washer.  I used plenty of hondabond on the threads of the drain bolt per the factory manual, and I'm wondering if I can get by without the washer.  Obviously I would like to avoid the hassle as well as avoid wasting coolant.  Will the hondabond and a properly torqued bolt be sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe. For a while. Perhaps. If the plug loosens or falls out, the engine may be damaged, you won't have a drain plug or coolant, and the car will be immobile.

Solution: get a big plastic tub. Drain coolant into the tub. Remove drain plug, add washer, reinstall plug. Refill cooling system using the coolant you just drained. Bleed the cooling system.

Comment: Is it likely for the plug to come loose with the hondabond on the threads? It has a temperature rating of 600 degrees f.

Comment: Whether it's likely or unlikely to fail, failure could result in damage and other unpleasant consequences. I'd choose to avoid those possibilities, and I would replace the washer. YMMV.